# Puppeteer unhandled rejection on waitForXPath

Tags: node.js, exception, puppeteer

I'm having trouble using `waitForXpath` to wait for an element that doesn't always show.

```
const isElementShown = await page
            .waitForXPath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/iframe', {
                visible: true,
                timeout: 12000,
            })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(`element shown: ${result}`);
                return result;
            })
            .catch(exception => console.log(`element not shown: ${exception}`));

if (isElementShown) {
    // do something
}
```

Even though I have the `.catch()`, the function stops executing and catches an exception here:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason: { stack: unknown }, promise) => {
    try {
        console.log(`SYSTEM WIDE UNHANDLED REJECTION: ${reason.stack}`);
        return reportError_async(`${reason.stack}`);
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log('exception', exception);
    }
    return null;
});
```

The exception message is:

```
Error: target should exist before targetInfoChanged
```

Using `Puppeteer v9.1.0`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the await with try/catch?

Comment: Yes actually, that was the original flow. I changed to this to be more granular.

Comment: Forgot to add the exception message... Should be more descriptive now.

Comment: I just executed this as a test, it also causes the same exception: 

`await page.waitForTimeout(1000).then(() => console.log('Waited a second!'));`

Comment: try something like:
`const isElementShown = await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/iframe', { visible: true, timeout: 12000 })` without the "then/catch"

Comment: that's what I had originally, with the try/catch around it. It didn't work.

Comment: Downgrading to `v2.1.1` fixed the issue. I will go up the versions tomorrow to see where it will break and share any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with the `9.1.0` version of Puppeteer. Version `9.1.1` resolves the issue.

Related Github issue: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/7203

Answer (score 0):

If you need all this only because you have then this condition:

```js
if (isElementShown) {
    // do something
}
```

why not use `page.$()`?

```js
const isElementShown = await page.$('html > body > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > iframe');
if (isElementShown) {
    // do something
}
```

It won't throw any exception if the element is not found. However, you cannot use xPath here, only CSS selectors enlisted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), but that should not be such a trouble.

Comment: XPath was the only option due to badly designed HTML (which is 3rd party). I can't change to CSS, otherwise, that would be a preferred option.

Comment: And yes, the whole code is only because of the conditional element.

Comment: @samuraijack: how about something like this selector: `html > body > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > iframe`? You should be able to reach it using CSS as well.